# Question about delayed sampled sinusoid math expression

Tags: math, audio, signal-processing

I have been studying the digital audio processing by using the book <Designing Audio Effect Plugins in C++>.

**For analog Sinusoid:**

Complex Sinusoid = e^(jωt)

Delayed Sinusoid = e^(jω(t−n)) = e^(jwt) * e^(-jwn), a delay of n seconds

**For digital sampled version:**

sampled complex sinusoid = e^(jωnT), T is interval for each sample, n is the index of sample

I understand all above, but I got confused about the **delayed sampled sinusoid** which described as: e^(jω ( nT −M )), M = samples of delay

But I think it should be described as e^(jωT( n − M )), since the T is a constant for a fixed sample rate, n and M has the same unit.

Anyone can explain it for me?

Comment: It's a good question, but not related to programming and as such fits https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ far better.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about `e^(jωT( n − M )),` when `M` represents delay as sample count

Formula `e^(jω ( nT −M ))` is valid for `M` as time

Comment: Thanks for your replay, you mean the book made a typo? But the follow computation parts of the book are all using the  e^(jω ( nT −M )) as basis.

Comment: I looked in the book and don't see any context that might make things more clear. But I've noticed using the same names for distinct values (like n as sample number and n as time in seconds), so I am not surprised if M stuff is just mistake.